# Is there any library to process scriptSig script in transaction, and other scripts?

Tags: blockchain, script, python, ruby

I'm trying to parse hex representation of scriptSig, in normal transactions there are variable int, r&s, pubkey. But some are really weird, like those ones:

```
6a26d2ecb67f27d1fa5524763b49029d7106e91e3cc05743073461a719776192
23befff6eea3dded0e34574af65c266c9398e7d7d9d07022bf1cd526c5cdbc94
825baed503ce5d28bf7332b6dac4751aaceea5cf2df9148b90cbc61894b65261
8e8b01b99048ee68bfe378dd7eb7fc8c1d5b1864aa74a76f4dc97ed38fbfe15e
```

I was not able to find any information on all types of transactions, their structure and how to decode them. There's always something new and non-standard still Bitcoin Core somehow decodes it.

Unfortunately I barely can read C++ code and sources of Bitcoin Core, but maybe there are any ruby\python\php code which I can use or at least understand how to decode each and every script on the blockchain? Or any documentation which describes all various valid scripts?

Comment: I know this isn't what you're looking for, but personal experience has taught me that the best reference for anything script-related is usually the Bitcoin Core code, itself.  That's why it's called the "reference client".  If you want to get into the low-level parts of the Bitcoin protocol, it's probably worth becoming more comfortable with C/C++.  That said, I'm sure somebody will suggest a library that does what you want.

Comment: python-bitcoinlib has support for parsing scripts. In the CScript module. You may be able to pretty print them using that library.

Comment: thanks guys, any documents about it except https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script ?

Comment: I don't use it but bitcoin-ruby seems to have implemented Script as well: https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby/blob/master/lib/bitcoin/script.rb